# Switching Two JPanels on same JFrame

Tags: java, swing

**Hello Everyone**
i want to create single JFrame containing two JPanels having same size and locations but different layouts and components. i want my JFrame that include two buttons also for switching JPanels.When i click first JButton the first JPanel appears on the JFrame second one does not appear on JFrame while one appears similarly while clicking second JButton,the second JPanel appears on JFrame and first one dispose...
I really need your help for doing so

Thank you..........

Comment: My initial thought would be to use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: or maybe you are looking for [Tabbed Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)